# Дублирующие объекты при получении списка Entity с составным ключом с помощью Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, key

Столкнулся с проблемой, с которой сам никак справиться не смог. Прошу помощи. Суть:
Имеется класс Vote с составным ключом из двух значений типа int userId и menuId. Также имеют два поля типа User и Menu id юзера совпадет с ключом userId, id меню с menuId соответственно. При вытаскивании из базы объекта vote по композитному ключу поля user и menu заполняются корректно. vote репозитории достаю из

```
EntityManager
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public Vote get(int userId, int menuId) {
    return em.find(Vote.class, new Vote.VoteCompositeKey(userId, menuId));
}
```

Но в Menu и в User есть List, которые на него ссылаются, и при доставании Юзера из базы в лист попадают не два vote, как должно быть, а 12. Причём, 5 дубликатов первого Vote и пять второго.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
         @Override
public User get(int id) {
    return em.find(User.class, id);
}
```

Грешу на композитный ключ. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и подскажет что делать, чтобы лист заполнялся корректно? Классы ниже

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@IdClass(Vote.VoteCompositeKey.class)
@Table(name = "votes",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id", 
"menu_id"}, name = "votes_idx"))
public class Vote implements Serializable {

@Id
private int userId;
@Id
private int menuId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@NotNull
private User user;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "menu_id", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@NotNull
private Menu menu;

public Vote() {
}

public Vote(User user, Menu menu) {
    this.user = user;
    this.menu = menu;
    this.userId = user.getId();
    this.menuId = menu.getId();
}

public Vote(Vote vote) {
    this(vote.getUser(), vote.getMenu());
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
    this.userId = user.getId();
}

public void setMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    this.menuId = menu.getId();
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public Menu getMenu() {
    return menu;
}

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}    

public int getMenuId() {
    return menuId;
}    

@Override
public String toString() {
    //реализация опущена
}

@Embeddable
public static class VoteCompositeKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "menu_id", nullable = false)
    private int menuId;

    public VoteCompositeKey() {
    }

    public VoteCompositeKey(int userId, int menuId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.menuId = menuId;
    }

    private int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    private void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public int getMenuId() {
        return menuId;
    }

    public void setMenuId(int menuId) {
        this.menuId = menuId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        VoteCompositeKey that = (VoteCompositeKey) o;

        if (userId != that.userId) return false;
        return menuId == that.menuId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = userId;
        result = 31 * result + menuId;
        return result;
    }
}
}
```

Он включает в себя два поля классов User и Menu:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name", name = "users_unique_name_idx"))
public class User extends AbstractNamedEntity {

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@CollectionTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id", "role"}, name = "user_roles_idx"))
@Column(name = "role")
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set <Role> roles;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
private List<Vote> votes;

public User(){
    super();
}

public User(String name, Set <Role> roles) {
    super(name);
    this.roles = roles;
}

public User(String name, Role role, Role... roles) {
    this(name, EnumSet.of(role, roles));
}

public User(Integer id, String name, Set <Role> roles) {
    super(id, name);
    this.roles = roles;
}

public User(Integer id, String name, Role role, Role... roles) {
    this(id, name, EnumSet.of(role, roles));
}

public User(User user) {
    this(user.getId(), user.getName(), user.getRoles());
}

public Set <Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public List<Vote> getVotes() {
    return votes;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User (" +
            "id=" + id +
            " name=" + name +
            " roles=" + roles +
            ')';
}
}
```

класс Menu

```
import org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.stereotypes.Immutable;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Menu.DELETE, query = "DELETE FROM Menu m WHERE m.id=:id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = Menu.ALL_SORTED, query = "SELECT m FROM Menu m ORDER BY m.date, m.restaurant.name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = Menu.ALL_BEETWEN, query = "SELECT m FROM Menu m WHERE m.date>=?1 AND m.date<=?2")
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "menus",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"restaurants_id", "date"}, name = "menus_idx"))
public class Menu extends AbsractBaseEntity {

public static final String DELETE = "Menu.delete";
public static final String ALL_SORTED = "Menu.getAllSorted";
public static final String ALL_BEETWEN = "Menu.getAllBeetwen";

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "restaurants_id")
@NotNull
private Restaurant restaurant;

@Column(name = "date")
@NotNull
@Immutable
private LocalDate date;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKeyColumn(name = "dish")
@Column(name = "price")
@CollectionTable(name = "prices", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "menu_id"),
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"menu_id", "dish"}, name = "prices_idx"))
@OrderBy("dish")
private Map <String, Float> price;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "menu")
private List <Vote> votes;

public Menu() {
    super();
}

public Menu(Restaurant restaurant, LocalDate date, Map <String, Float> price) {
    this.restaurant = restaurant;
    this.date = date;
    this.price = price;
}

public Menu(Integer id, Restaurant restaurant, LocalDate date, Map <String, Float> menu) {
    super(id);
    this.restaurant = restaurant;
    this.date = date;
    this.price = menu;
}

public Menu(Integer id, Restaurant restaurant, LocalDate date, Map <String, Float> price, List <Vote> votes) {
    super(id);
    this.restaurant = restaurant;
    this.date = date;
    this.price = price;
    this.votes = votes;
}

public Menu(Menu menu) {
    this(menu.getId(), menu.getRestaurant(), menu.getDate(), menu.getMenu(), menu.getVotes());
}

public Restaurant getRestaurant() {
    return restaurant;
}

public LocalDate getDate() {
    return date;
}

public Map <String, Float> getMenu() {
    return price;
}

public List <Vote> getVotes() {
    return votes;
}

public void setRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) {
    this.restaurant = restaurant;
}

public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public void setPrice(Map <String, Float> price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public void setVotes(List <Vote> votes) {
    this.votes = votes;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Menu (" +
            "id=" + id +
            " restaurant=" + restaurant +
            " date=" + date +
            " menu=" + price +
            " votes=" + votes +
            ')';
}

}
```

запрос Хибернейта и лог ошибки

```
    Hibernate: 
select
    menu0_.id as id1_0_0_,
    menu0_.date as date2_0_0_,
    menu0_.restaurants_id as restaura3_0_0_,
    price1_.menu_id as menu_id1_1_1_,
    price1_.price as price2_1_1_,
    price1_.dish as dish3_1_,
    restaurant2_.id as id1_2_2_,
    restaurant2_.name as name2_2_2_,
    votes3_.menu_id as menu_id1_5_3_,
    votes3_.user_id as user_id2_5_3_,
    votes3_.menu_id as menu_id1_5_4_,
    votes3_.user_id as user_id2_5_4_,
    user4_.id as id1_4_5_,
    user4_.name as name2_4_5_,
    roles5_.user_id as user_id1_3_6_,
    roles5_.role as role2_3_6_ 
from
    menus menu0_ 
left outer join
    prices price1_ 
        on menu0_.id=price1_.menu_id 
left outer join
    restaurants restaurant2_ 
        on menu0_.restaurants_id=restaurant2_.id 
left outer join
    votes votes3_ 
        on menu0_.id=votes3_.menu_id 
left outer join
    users user4_ 
        on votes3_.user_id=user4_.id 
left outer join
    user_roles roles5_ 
        on user4_.id=roles5_.user_id 
where
    menu0_.id=? 
order by
    price1_.dish
    20:38:29.925 DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver:143 - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:hsqldb:file:D:/temp/voting]

    java.lang.AssertionError: 
    Expecting value <[Vote (userId=100001 menuId=100007), Vote (userId=100002 menuId=100007)]> in field <"votes"> but was <[Vote (userId=100001 menuId=100007),
Vote (userId=100001 menuId=100007),
Vote (userId=100002 menuId=100007),
Vote (userId=100001 menuId=100007),
Vote (userId=100001 menuId=100007),
Vote (userId=100002 menuId=100007),
Vote (userId=100001 menuId=100007),
Vote (userId=100001 menuId=100007),
Vote (userId=100002 menuId=100007),
Vote (userId=100001 menuId=100007),
Vote (userId=100001 menuId=100007),
Vote (userId=100002 menuId=100007)]> in <Menu (id=100007 restaurant=Restaurant (id=100004 name=Eleon) date=2018-05-09 menu={eggs=12.2, rabbit=4.3, rooster=8.96, soup=3.86} votes=[Vote (userId=100001 menuId=100007), Vote (userId=100001 menuId=100007), Vote (userId=100002 menuId=100007), Vote (userId=100001 menuId=100007), Vote (userId=100001 menuId=100007), Vote (userId=100002 menuId=100007), Vote (userId=100001 menuId=100007), Vote (userId=100001 menuId=100007), Vote (userId=100002 menuId=100007), Vote (userId=100001 menuId=100007), Vote (userId=100001 menuId=100007), Vote (userId=100002 menuId=100007)])>.
   Comparison was performed on all fields
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблему с дублированием удалось решить с помощью аннотации org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch с параметром FetchMode.SUBSELECT добавленной к полю-коллекции

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "menu")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List <Vote> votes;
```